Questions about code in overleaf template
I’m new in LaTeX. I found this cheat sheet template in overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/hoja-de-ecuaciones-electricidad-y-magnetismo/xwgjqkrjjgcb
I’m trying to understand the code. Can someone please explain what does each of the following lines do? They are in lines 20, 21, 35 and 36 respectively.
\newcommand*\bigcdot{\mathpalette\bigcdot@{.5}}
\newcommand*\bigcdot@[2]{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{\scalebox{#2}{$\m@th#1\bullet$}}}}}
\newcommand{\hr}{\centerline{\rule{3.5in}{1pt}}}
%\colorbox[HTML]{e4e4e4}{\makebox[\textwidth-2\fboxsep][l]{texto}

Also, I think some of these lines are not even used in the document, if so, I would like to know which of these are not used. Thanks

Line 4 does nothing, it is commented out

The first two lines (incorrectly) define a larger centered bullet operator. The third line (not using good latex style) defines a centered horizontal rule, and the 4th line does nothing as it is a comment. just try \hr  in a paragraph to see the effect an $a \bigcdot b$ to see the bigcdot.

@DavidCarlisle How would they have to be defined to be correct? What would the fourth line do if it wasn't s comment?

@DavidCarlisle What would be a good latex style for the third line?
